# Is there a way to make grid items always have the same gap when previous row/column items size automatically?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have a 3-column grid with its items' heights changing depending on the amount of content they have inside. Currently, the next column will always follow the largest item as the starting point for the gap, which looks like this:
[image]

I want it so that every grid item follows the previous column and row, and not have extra unwanted space due to some other item on the same column being larger than the other ones:
[image]

Is there a way to achieve this styling? I want to note that I don't set the item heights manually. I saw another post with a similar question but the person was using set heights for their grid items, instead of them expanding depending on their content like I do.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the `columns` property instead of grid.

For example:

```
.container{
    columns: 3
}

.item{
    break-inside: avoid
}
```

You'll get something like:
https://ayushm.vercel.app/#projects